# Form submit hook not executing

Tags: forms

In a drupal 6 custom module I built, I have a menu callback which contains this:

```
function mymodule_register_confirmation() {
  return drupal_get_form('mymodule_newsletter_form');
}
```

I have the function that returns the form:

```
function mymodule_newsletter_form(&$form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['logo'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#value' => '<div class="logo-header">',
  );

  ...

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit')
  );

  ...

  return $form;
}
```

I also built the function for the submit hook of newsletter form:

```
function mymodule_newsletter_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    die('I am in the submit hook!!');
}
```

The page shows as expected and contains the newsletter form exactly as I want. However, when I click the submit button, it goes to the action of the form (as expected) but the submit hook I built never executes. I even tried adding the following to the function that returns the form:

```
$form['submit']['#executes_submit_callback'] = TRUE;
$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_newsletter_form_submit';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you clear the cache? Generally, `$form['#submit'][]` should work. Also try to add a validation handler and find out it is invoked - `$form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_newsletter_form_validaton';`

Comment: Is your module name is `mymodule_newsletter`

Comment: @SithuKyaw: added the validation handler it is not called either.

Comment: @SumitMadan: no, this test module is called "mymodule".

Comment: @RolandPish Please change the name mymodule_newsletter_form to mymodule_form and check.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhh, found the problem!

I had to specify manually a redirect to the form:

```
$form['#redirect'] = ''; // Redirects to the home page
```

This way the validate and submit hooks are called appropriately and then it redirects to the home page.

Thank you all for all your replies. I appreciate it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Without the additional `$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_newsletter_form_submit';`, your code works just fine as is (pasted into a clean d6 install). There has to be something else going on that's preventing the submit handler from executing.

Comment: Mmm, interesting. I will have to dig in into the other custom modules to see if something is going on in there.
Thanks a lot Sean!